# How to shade a package and all its dependencies in maven?

Tags: maven

We want to shade a third party library (Example: `com.esotericsoftware.kryo`) and all its dependencies and repackage them with a different package name so that the final jar does not have version conflicts when included within other projects.

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>example.shade.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproj-shade-kryo</artifactId>
    <name>myproj-shade-kryo</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esotericsoftware.kryo</groupId>
            <artifactId>kryo</artifactId>
            <version>2.21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createSourcesJar>true</createSourcesJar>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                           <include>com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo</include>
                        </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                           <artifact>com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo</artifact>
                        </filter>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.esotericsoftware.kryo</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>example.shade.group.kryo</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I look inside the final shaded jar file, I see that only `com.esotericsoftware.kryo` is repackaged but not the dependencies of kryo.

If I do not repackage the dependencies of kryo too, then version conflicts in those dependencies might still be there if the users of my jar include other versions of kryo.

If I package all the dependencies of kryo, then it might quickly become very painful to do this for all the dependencies.

What is the recommended solution for such a case?

Comment: Shading is done "per package" not "per dependency", by the time you're shading classes, you don't even know which library they are coming from. You'll need to shade each package of the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Tunaki, So I have to specify packages for all the dependencies then? I would have expected something like a repackage-all kind of configuration which just adds my custom package-name to the beginning of all the packages in the dependencies. This would solve the version problem even if my users included different version of the same dependencies.

Comment: I think you need to, yes. The plugin works on the classpath, so it can't know whether a given class came from libA or libB and whether that was a transitive dependency of some other library.